# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '' (111 "Connection refused")

Tags: mysql, sockets, connection, mariadb

I am using Mariadb 10.1.34 on Centos 7.3. All DB servers have same configuration and they are working properly.

However one DB server is unable to locally connect through socket (`/mysqldata/mysql/mysql.sock`).

Error:

```
mysql -uroot -p 

Enter password: ********* 

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '' (111 "Connection refused")
```

I perceive from the Error that the MySql client is unable to find the socket file (`/mysqldata/mysql/mysql.sock`).

If we mention the socket file:

```
mysql -uroot -p -S /mysqldata/mysql/mysql.sock 

Enter password: *********
```

Then the MySql client connects properly.

Despite that I have defined `socket=/mysqldata/mysql/mysql.sock` in the `[MYSQLD]` and `[client]` sections of the configuration file (`/etc/my.cnf`).

The socket file is created on `"service mariadb start"` and deleted on `"service mariadb stop"`. The MySql client is unable to find the socket file.

Help is needed to resolve this problem.